# Load more Webview inside NestedScrollView

Tags: android, webview, pagination, android-nestedscrollview

I have a WebView having Loadmore (Pagination) functionality. I need it to be inside of NestedScrollview to give collapsing effect. If webview is outside of NestedScrollview Loadmore functionality is working fine. But LoadMore is not working if it is inside of NestedScrollview. Following is my xml code. Please help to resolve this issue.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                             xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                             android:id="@+id/main_content"
                                             android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                             android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                             android:background="@drawable/bg_wall">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_backdrop_height"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

            <!--CONTAINS OTHER VIEWS-->

        </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@null"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    app:behavior_overlapTop="40dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/mainCard"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp">

            <!--CONTAINS OTHER VIEWS-->

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="@dimen/wall_pro_pic_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/wall_pro_pic_size"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:elevation="100dp">

              <!--CONTAINS OTHER VIEWS-->

        </RelativeLayout>

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webview_openbusiness"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/mainCard"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@null"/>

       <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/webview_progress"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```